# Fortran module read file

Tags: fortran

I am trying to write a module to contain all my data. And the data is stored in a txt file. And I am wondering if everytime I use the module in my main program, the module will read the file again? I want the module only read the file once at the first time I call the module and store it as global variable. So that I can speed up my main program by cutting time wasting on opening and reading files. May I know how can I achieve that? Thank you!

```
MODULE DATA

implicit none

contains

Subroutine readfile(indexnum, filename1, filename2, filename3, rootpath,b1, 
b2, SOFX, SOFY, Lx, Ly)

Character(400) ::indexnum, filename1, filename2, filename3, rootpath
real ::b1, b2, SOFX, SOFY, Lx, Ly


Open(unit = 11, file = "D:\rootpath.txt")

Read (11,*) rootpath

close (unit = 11)



filename1 = trim(rootpath)//"\index number.txt"

Open (unit = 51, file = filename1)

read (51, *) indexnum

close (unit = 51)



filename1 = trim(rootpath)//"\SOFandN.txt"

Open (unit = 72, file = filename1)

read (72, *) SOFX, SOFY, Lx, Ly

close (unit = 72)
return

End subroutine readfile
End module data
```

Comment: Does this even compile? I think you should put your code into a subroutine or function, which you explicitly need to call to read in a file.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt, Thank you for your reply. How about I includes a subroutine in the module? If my main program use the module 4 times, does it means that the subroutine will be called 4 times as well(the file is read 4 times)?